# JSONP - express: Why does the browser ignore the request?

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, jsonp

I wrote the following HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>HTML page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src='http://localhost:3000?callback=mycallbackFunction'> </script>
    <script>
        function mycallbackFunction(data) {
            alert('here');
            alert (data['a']);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, the script tag includes a JSONP request to a remote server.

In addition, I wrote the following node.js file and ran it as a server:

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.jsonp({'a': 'blabla'});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

After I had run the node.js file and opened the browser with the html page, I expected to see a pop-up window of alert. But, no. I didn't see anything.

The Network Tab in Developer Tools shows that the request has been accepted: 
[image]

Do you know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap the order of your `<script>` elements.

Explanation:

Express is correctly serving a script that looks like `myCallbackFunction({'a': 'blabla'})`, which is exactly what you hoped for. However, this script runs immediately, and `myCallbackFunction` has yet to be defined, so nothing happens. Then, in the next `<script>` block, you define `myCallbackFunction`, but this is useless, since the (failed) call has already happened in the previous `<script>`.

Also, you have a case mismatch on the `C` in `mycallbackFunction` -- make sure the capitalization agrees between the callback parameter and the name of your function.

Comment: You're right. I changed the order of script tags and fixed the 'C' and it works!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to switch the order of both script tags:

```
<body>
    <script>
        function mycallbackFunction(data) {
            alert('here');
            alert (data['a']);
        }
    </script>
    <script src='http://localhost:3000?callback=mycallbackFunction'>  </script>
</body>
```